# Best way to determine that two sets of sample means are not different (with 95% confidence)?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean

I am given the averages and standard deviations of two sets of data. The average is computed by running a non-specific optimization algorithm 30 times and averaging the result. I am trying to determine if my data is "equal" to the data given in a research paper with 95% confidence.

Which statistical test would be most apt for such a comparison?

Comment: Are you looking for a test or for a confidence interval of the difference between the two means ? What algorithm? Normal data? What sample sizes?

Comment: The most common tools would be confidence intervals for the difference or equivalence tests (when you have a specific standard of what counts as 'equivalent'). When performing a test, don't use the word "confidence" to refer to $1-\alpha$. Just frame it in terms of the significance level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at this wrong! Almost certainly, your data is **not** "equal" to the data given in a research paper and it would be silly to try to claim that they are equal when there is any amount of difference.

Let's turn the question around and see if we can give you a partial answer. Suppose these two sets of data are generated by a random process with means $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and standard deviations $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. Even if $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are the same, both equal to $\mu$ lets say, then the resulting data sets can look different. It sounds like you would like to use Statistics to identify *the level of disagreement between data sets that you might reasonably expect to see*, given that the population means are the same. Next, you can consider that if the two data sets in real life differ by considerably more than this, a likely conclusion is that the premise $\mu_1=\mu_2=\mu$ is *false*.

The test you are probably looking for is the [two sample t test](https://www.jmp.com/en_us/statistics-knowledge-portal/t-test/two-sample-t-test.html), but you should really think about what these tests mean and how to **correctly** interpret the results before you start plugging and chugging.

[This article](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-019-00857-9) is a nice introduction to some of the common traps, mostly related to interpretation, that practitioners run into with hypothesis testing.